# What is the best way to save comma separated keywords posted from client side into database table using Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, tastypie

I have a text area input on a simple HTML page, where I am posting comma-separated keywords to save into my database table.
For example,
Keywords input is like: `keyword1,keyword2,keyword3, ...`

[image]

I am using Django 3.2 and Tastypie as a API framework.

Here is my Django model:

```
class Keywords(models.Model):
    keyword = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'keywords'
```

And Tastypie resource:

```
class KeywordResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta(CommonMeta):
        queryset = Keywords.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'keyword-resource'
        filtering = {'id': ALL, 'keyword': ALL}
        allowed_methods = ['get', 'post', 'put', 'patch']
```

I want to save the comma-separated keyword in one post request from the client side. How can I post comma-separated keywords and insert them one by one into the table `Keywords`?
Also, what would be the best way to use `save()` method from model or `hydrate()` method from tastypie resource to prepare the data to save?

Answer (score 0):

you can override the `hydrate` and the `obj_create` method

```
from tastypie.authorization import Authorization

class KeywordResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta(CommonMeta):
        queryset = Keywords.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'keyword-resource'
        filtering = {'id': ALL, 'keyword': ALL}
        allowed_methods = ['get', 'post', 'put', 'patch']
        authorization = Authorization()

    def hydrate(self, bundle):
        # Retrieve the comma-separated keywords from the input data
        keywords = bundle.data.get('keywords', '')  # Assuming the input field is named 'keywords'
        
        # Split the keywords, remove leading/trailing whitespace, and create a list
        keyword_list = [kw.strip() for kw in keywords.split(',') if kw.strip()]
        
        # Update the 'keywords' field in the bundle data with the processed list
        bundle.data['keywords'] = keyword_list
        
        return bundle

    def obj_create(self, bundle, **kwargs):
        # Retrieve the list of keywords from the bundle data
        keyword_list = bundle.data.get('keywords')
        
        # Loop through each keyword and create or retrieve it in the 'Keywords' table
        for keyword in keyword_list:
            keyword_obj, created = Keywords.objects.get_or_create(keyword=keyword)
        
        return bundle
```

Comment: Do I have to override both methods or one of them is enough to insert keywords?

Comment: I am getting this error in `obj_create()` `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''`. Any idea how and why?